# Closure of 'Where can you rent watercraft to explore the 30,000 islands in Georgian Bay?'

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Why was [Where can you rent watercraft to explore the 30,000 islands in Georgian Bay?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57549/13759) closed, when it resembles [these questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+you+can+rent)?

Comment: FWIW, it's never worth comparing to legacy questions, as the community evolves, rules adapt, and what might have been eligible or on topic in the past isn't always now.

Comment: @MarkMayo I think it's always worth comparing to them, in order to learn why things have changed (and to allow the community to consider whether that shift is appropriate).  It's never possible to _rely_ on past questions.

Comment: @Joe indeed, rely is a better word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was one of the voters.  Terribly sorry.  From my view, it looks like a question where the only factual answer that could be acceptable is the name of a company that rents watercraft.  The answer would be treated as an endorsement, something like trip adviser, and this site has a very strong pull with search engines.

Hence, the site has a rule that shopping questions are off-topic.

You have pointed to some questions very similar to yours and ask why they are not closed also.  The answer is that the site, like all SO sites, is self regulating and the regulating surface is massively uneven.  There are inconsistencies, and it's part of 'what is'.

I have had questions closed and can attest that it is an unpleasant experience, but that's the way the community operates.  You can try to edit it such that the single correct factual answer is not the name of a company and then reopen it.

Comment: We've generally not had problems naming companies, as long as one makes it clear you're not affiliated, or if you are, that you declare it.

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: +1. Thank you. No need for sorriness!